# How to set hidden element/text/id in background for visible text in pdf document

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am giving internal link in pdf document using pdfbox library. For that I am comparing the string and get the co-ordinates of string from pdf document and add link on string. This is working fine and here is the [link](https://github.com/vbthakkar9/internal-link).
Now, I have two same string and I want to redirect to two different pages like following

```
Link 1 -> redirects to Page 3
Link 1 -> redirects to Page 5
```

Is there any way that while creating pdf I add some hidden element/text/id in **Link 1** in background from which I can identify on which page I should redirect.